# React Hook: Why is my alert different from the props received?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React hooks. I'm trying to display a props received from another component in a small alert.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";

const Alert = props => {
  const alert = useAlert();
  console.log("<< @ Alert props.message", props.message); // Diplays "deputy saved"

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button
        className="btn btn-outline-secondary"
        onClick={() => {
          alert.show(props.message); // Displays the previous props received. Not the one from the console log above.
        }}
      >
        Ajouter
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

Here is the component in which the alert is rendered. The message is setstate after being fetched by my Api file. This message contains the res.json from my Node server. For example "deputy created" or "this deputy already exists". The message is then sent to the alert component via an attribute and received as a props.

```
  // AddParty Component
import React from "react";
import { Form, Text, TextArea } from "informed";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Alert from "../../core/admin/Alert";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import Api from "../../../utils/Api";

class AddParty extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: {},
      message: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange({ name, value }) {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  async onSubmit(formState) {
    console.info("formState", formState);

    const { image } = this.state;

    const newParty = new FormData();
    newParty.append("image", image, image.name);
    newParty.append("data", JSON.stringify(formState));

    const message = await Api.addParty(newParty);
    console.log("message :", message);
    this.setState({
      message
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { message, isSubmitted } = this.state;
    console.log("message", message);

    return (
      <Container className="container">
        <Form onSubmit={formState => this.onSubmit(formState)}>
          <Label>
            Nom du parti:
            <Text
              field="name"
              type="text"
              className="form-control form-control-sm"
            />
          </Label>
          <Label>
            Description :
            <TextArea
              field="description"
              className="form-control form-control-sm"
            />
          </Label>
          <Label>
            Photo:
            <input
              type="file"
              onChange={event =>
                this.handleChange({
                  name: "image",
                  value: event.target.files[0]
                })
              }
            />
          </Label>
          <Alert
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-outline-secondary"
            message={message}
          />
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default AddParty;
```

I don't understand why the alert displayed is always the one from the previous props received, not the one showing in the console.log

Comment: because you should change the props to watch new changes. how you change the alert component props ?!

Comment: @Alex what you are saying doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please show where you render `Alert`

Comment: I edited my question with the render @Vencovsky. Thank you guys for your comments

Comment: What you are saying is literally not possible inside a function component with no state.

Comment: Did you try not using a Fragment and just using a "<div/>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using another react alert module called react-toastify. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify
Thanks you to all that helped me